# Port 80 to 8080

Tags: xampp, localhost

First time I installed the package xampp I had many problems (like everyone who tries to use this programs and tries to create a website!)

I had made some researches on the web to find the solution to make Apache work: I setted the usual port 80 to 8080.

Now everytime I want to access to control panel of xampp or access to the DBMS MySQL I have always to add to the url ":8080" after "localhost".

My first question is: is it possible not to write ":8080" after the "localhost", maybe changing some settings I don't know where or in what file? (ex: "localhost:8080/xampp/" => "localhost/xampp")

Another thing: what could be the problems if apache is listening on the port 8080 instead of the usual one? (I don't have many experience in this field...)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to not write :8080 in the address bar is to make it work with the default port, which is :80. If the server does not want to start on that port it's probably because another program is already using it.

```
netstat -a -n -o | findstr ":80 "
```

With this command you can see which program is using your 80 port.

Comment: Can we change the port of that programs without risking a collapse? And how can we do it with the command prompt (if it is possible) ?

Comment: In my case it is telling me that is my computer who is using it. What does it mean? I used the -f parameter to see the names...

Comment: If those programs allows you to change the port, then yes. To find the program, just type the command that i've wrote above and look for something like 0.0.0.0:80, then get it's PID from the last column on the right and then type this command: tasklist /FI "PID eq 1234" where 1234 is the pid you've got.

Comment: But in my case the computer is telling me that I don't have a task running on that port. I printed the command exactly as you said (tasklist /FI "PID eq 80"). But I saw before that I have some programs that are running with that port when I typed this command: ' netstat -a -n -o | findstr ":80" '

Comment: You should use thee tasklist command with the PID of the program that you found with netstat. For example you can see this with the netstat command: "TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 440". Now you type tasklist /FI "PID eq 440" and you will get the process name for that PID, which is 440 in this example.